# replace a certain value of specific key in list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
list1 = [{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': '15423'},{'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': '8548305'}, {'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': '15423'}]
```

I want to convert anything that has address with 15423 to 'Valid' and all the other cases Invalid
Final output

```
list1 = [{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': 'Valid'},{'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': 'Invalid'}, {'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': 'Valid'}]
```

Here is what I tried

```
if '15423' in list1['address']:
    list1['address'] = 'Valid'
else:
    list1['address'] = 'Invalid'
```

But I am not sure why it is not working. Maybe I need to loop through the whole column.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the elements of `list1` using a `for` loop, since `list1` is a list of dictionaries:

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if '15423' in list1[i]['address']:
        list1[i]['address'] = 'Valid'
    else:
        list1[i]['address'] = 'Invalid'
        
print(list1)
```

You can also condense the `if/else` into a ternary if you're looking for a more concise solution:

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i]['address'] = 'Valid' if '15423' in list1[i]['address'] else 'Invalid'
```

Both of these print:

```py
[{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': 'Valid'},
{'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': 'Invalid'},
{'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': 'Valid'}]
```

Comment: I don't know why but all the values have Invalid, so for some reasons it doesn't consider the valid case

Comment: @YanRemes Edited, try now.

Comment: It is still Invalid for all of them

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Please confirm that the sample data that you've given is correct.

Comment: Yeah that is my data but it seems like it doesn't go through the if statement and considers only the else statement

Comment: I'm not sure then. Again, I can't reproduce the issue you're describing, so there's unfortunately not much I can do here.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Refer  mine solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

you have to loop through the list!

---

### Why?

let's say `num_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]`

using a `for` loop like so:

```py
for item in num_list:
    ...
```

will loop through `num_list` as you'd expect. `item` will be set to the current value, in this case, it will set `item` to `1`, do the code in the loop, then set `item` to `2`, then do the code in the loop again, and so on.

now let's say `num_list = [{"number": 0}, {"number": 1}, {"number": 2}, {"number": 3}]`.

this time, if you run the same `for` loop, `item` will still be set to the current value, in this case, it will set it to the *dictionary* instead of the number. thus, `item` is set to `{"number": 0}`, then the code inside the loop will run, then `item` is set to `{"number": 1}`, then the code inside the loop will run again, etc.

thus, `item` will be set to a dictionary, which by then you can edit like any other dictionary! simply do `item["number"] = ...`

---

for the actual fixed code, here ya go

```py
list1 = [
    {'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': '15423'},
    {'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': '8548305'},
    {'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': '15423'}
]


for item in list1:
    if item["address"] == "15423":
        item["address"] = "Valid"
    else:
        item["address"] = "Invalid"

print(list1)
```

output:

```py
[
    {'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': 'Valid'},
    {'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': 'Invalid'},
    {'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': 'Valid'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of have answered the question. Refer the below solution as well for few points:

You have dictionaries in a list, hence you need to first iterate over each element and access dictionary. While iteration check if address key is present in dictionary or not and then apply the if condition. If we use `item['address']` then possibilities are that code might break if we didn't find address key in any of the dictionary. Hence use `item.get('address')` to extract the value.

Here is the code:

```
list1 = [
{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': '15423'},
{'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': '8548305'},
{'time': '2019', 'name': 'five', 'address': '15423'}
]


for item in list1:
    if item.get('address'):
         if item.get('address')== "15423":
             item["address"] = "Valid"
         else:
             item["address"] = "Invalid"
print(list1)
```